# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while running twitter connector using flume

Tags: java, twitter, flume

I am starting the agent using this command

bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent

My error messages are

```
Exception in thread "Twitter Stream consumer-1[Receiving stream]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:367)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamBase.handleNextElement(StatusStreamBase.java:85)
    at twitter4j.StatusStreamImpl.next(StatusStreamImpl.java:57)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:478)
18/05/15 16:53:36 ERROR hdfs.HDFSEventSink: process failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My property file of twitter.conf given below

```
# Naming the components on the current agent.
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

# Describing/Configuring the source
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = kafka

# Describing/Configuring the sink

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://xxx:7200/topics/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100000

# Describing/Configuring the channel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000

# Binding the source and sink to the channel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
```

My flume-env.sh file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

# Give Flume more memory and pre-allocate, enable remote monitoring via JMX
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"


# Let Flume write raw event data and configuration information to its log files for debugging
# purposes. Enabling these flags is not recommended in production,
# as it may result in logging sensitive user information or encryption secrets.
# export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.flume.log.rawdata=true -Dorg.apache.flume.log.printconfig=true "

# Note that the Flume conf directory is always included in the classpath.
#FLUME_CLASSPATH=""

# export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
# export HCAT_HOME=/usr/lib/hive-hcatalog
```

i have update export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" in flume-env.sh file, but still getting java heap memory issue. What should i do to resolve this issue further.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue increasing the heap size, by adding this line in twitter.conf file

```
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.byteCapacity = 6912212
```

Then increased the heap size in flume-env.sh file

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line in your `flume-env.sh` file

`export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"`

Then start the agent

Comment: after i comment that line also i am getting the same issue

Comment: Exception in thread "Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Exception in thread "Twitter Stream consumer-1[Receiving stream]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space