# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in flume

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, flume

**Issue** : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in flume.

**Executing COMMAND** :

```
flume-ng agent --conf conf 
--conf-file /usr/local/flume/conf/twitter.conf --name TwitterAgent
-Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG.console
```

**Output :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Conf File
[config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8c1X.png)

Flume env.sh
[flume-env.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLtnA.png)

Comment: There is insufficient information in your Question for us to help you.  Try reading some of the existing Q&As about flume and OOMEs; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349540.  Or add more details ... such as relevant config files, version information, stacktraces, things that you have tried, etc.

Comment: export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms400m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"    this is the memory allocation in my flume-env.sh.     I am using jdk 11 and flume version 1.8.0

Comment: What you said then contradicts your question.  9.7G is not the same as 2G.  Maybe you should read the manual entry for the `java` command to understand what the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options you are using actually mean.

Comment: java -Xmx10000m  -XshowSettings:all , when I run this command to know my settings of heap space this came up and that's why I shared this 
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size: 9.77G
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: I have 3.5Gb ram and even if I set the max heap space to 3GB , it shows me the same error. I may  be sound naive and I am but I really need help in this

Comment: Well I don't see how we can help you given the minimal (and contradictory!) information you have given us.  It may simply be that the problem you are trying to solve is too big for a machine with 3.5GB of RAM.  But like I said, we can't help if you don't explain.

Comment: and by default my max heap space is 841 mb

Comment: Okay please let me know what all information you require and i will provide you with it.

Comment: Once again.  Insufficient information.

Comment: Describe in detail the problem that you are trying to solve.  And show us the config file.

Comment: I have attached the images of conf file and flume-env.sh in the question , please check it out and let me know if you need anymore information. My problem is whenever I run my flume agent I get this OutOfMemory error and I havn't found a solution yet. I use a VM to run flume with 3.5 gb of ram and amd reyzon 5 processor and jdk 11 with flume version 1.8.0. conf file and flume-env.sh are given in the question itself

Comment: I would recommend that you reset the secret that you showed us in that image.  We don't need to know >>that<< to help you ...

Answer (score 0):

I compared the config that you are using with the example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_flume/fetching_twitter_data.htm), and I can't see any mistakes.  The only differences I could see are:

- you used a smaller value for `TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity`
- you used a smaller for `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchsize` and `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollcount`
- the `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path` is different.

I wouldn't have thought that any of those would *increase* memory utilisation.

The other thing to check would be whether data is actually flowing into HDFS.  The [same source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_flume/fetching_twitter_data.htm) says that you should use the Hadoop Administration Web UI to check that data is flowing into Hadoop.  I imagine if that if data is not flowing, then it could be accumulating in the heap of the flume-ng application.  If too much data accumulates, you will eventually overflow the heap.  No matter what you set the heap size too.

Possible reasons why the data might not be flowing include:

- Hadoop is not running.
- Hadoop is running on a different host (or IP) and/or port to the one that you have specified in your flume config file.